A question on binary strings and bit swapping.
I consider binary strings over the bit-alphabet $\{0,1\}$. A binary string $S$ is balanced if the number of occurrences in $S$ of the bit $0$ is the same as the number of occurrences of the bit $1$; $S$ is regular if no two consecutive occurrences of a bit in $S$ are occurrences of the same bit. The question is: given a balanced binary string $S$, find the shortest binary string $\sigma$ such that, for some permutation $\pi$ of $\sigma$, there is a sequence of binary strings $S_0,S_1,\ldots,S_n$, with $n\geqslant 0$, satisfying the following conditions:

$S_0=S$;
$S_n$ is regular;
for each $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$, there are binary strings $X$ and $Y$ such that $S_{i-1}=X\sigma Y$ and $S_{i}=X\pi Y$.


Let $S=0011$ and see what happens.

Are you sure about the details? For example, if $S_0=0011$, then there doesn’t exist a substring $10$ in $S_0$, making the conditions unsatisfiable.

I'm sorry, I posted the wrong question. I just edited it.

@Nellina  Is this home work?  What level of formality are you after?  Have you tried something?  Can you at least envision (maybe with the help of some paper-and-pen) what the answer should be?

Am I correct in understanding your definition of "regular"? For a given length, the only regular strings would be 101010... and 010101...?

This is not homework. I tried to answer the question by proceeding by induction on the length $|S|$ of the input string $S$, but failed. (Note that, for $|S|\in{0,2}$, we have that $\sigma\in{S,S^{R}}$, where $S^{R}$ is the reversal of $S$. Also, observe that $\sigma$ can always be found, since there is a permutation $S'$ of $S$ such that $S'$ is regular).
Yes, the set of regular binary strings is $(01)^{}\cup(10)^{}$ (${}^{*}$ denotes the Kleene Star Operator).

FYI - You are automatically notified of all comments on your posts, but commenters are not automatically notified of your replies. To manually notify someone, in your comment, preceed their username with an @ sign, with all spaces removed: @Nellina.

The minimal patterns $\sigma$ and $\pi$ are going to change from string to string. You already have this with Parcly Taxel's example and its inverse: $0011$ and $1100$. The first needs $\sigma = 01, \pi = 10$, while the second needs $\sigma = 10, \pi = 01$. Some strings may require a permutation involving half the bits. For example, no permutation involving two or three bits can make $11000011$ regular, as it would need to move $0$s both foward and aft.

I guess that, in the case $S = 11000011$, the only solutions (with $|\sigma|<|S|$) are $(\sigma=1000011, \pi=0101010)$ and $(\sigma=1100001 , \pi=0101010)$.
